# Object doesn't support this action error on a simple Powerpoint chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a macro running from an Excel file that interacts with some charts on a powerpoint file. The part of the code below is throwing the error "Object doesn't support this action" when it reaches the .Chart.PlotArea.Height = 90 line.

```
Dim PPT_object As PowerPoint.Application
With PPT_object.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(4).Shapes.Range
 If .HasChart Then
   .Chart.PlotArea.Height = 90
  End If
End With
```

Can someone help me to understand why this line is giving this error?
Thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

`.Chart.PlotArea.Height = 90` ia referring to `.Shapes.Range` whereas it should refer to `.Shapes`

Change

```
With PPT_object.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(4).Shapes.Range
```

to

```
With PPT_object.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(4).Shapes(Relevant shape no)
```

Your code can be written as  (**UNTESTED**)

```
Dim PPT_object As PowerPoint.Application
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape

'~~> Change this to the relevant shape number
Set shp = PPT_object.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1)

If shp.HasChart Then shp.Chart.PlotArea.Height = 90
```

Comment: it didn't worked. I've tried both approaches but it throws the error: "Method 'Height' of object 'PlotArea' Failed". I also tried a small change on the code (see below) but I got the same error.
Dim shapeCount As Long
shapeCount = PPT_object.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(4).Shapes.Count
Set shp = PPT_object.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(4).Shapes(shapeCount)
If shp.HasChart Then shp.Chart.PlotArea.Height = 90